# How can i keep the Menu open with JavaScript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a `SideBar` Menu, how can i keep it open? If you go to the page, the Menu is closed and i must click on the Menu Button, to toggle it on. How can i keep it open, i'll close it myself.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#nav-btn').click(toggleMenu);
   $('main').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    toggleMenu();
    }
    });
    function toggleMenu() {
    $('#nav-btn, #sidebar, main, #cover').toggleClass('active');
}
</script>
```

Comment: You defined the event ".click" so you need to click on it. Also define the ".ready" event and it should be done. Or, simply add the "active" class on your code

Comment: Give the element with the id `main` the class `active` to begin with....

Answer (score 0):

- for better practice, write your code inside a `.js` doc and put your code inside a

  ```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  // Your code here
  });
  ```

  And not inside a `<script>` tag..
- You can just add the `active` classes inside the HTML element (wihthout jQuery), if debugging is the purpose.
- Try replacing `toggleClass` with `addClass`, should help.
- **Please** edit your question and provide the **full** code (html & css) so we can help you further